# Redux Action return undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

So, I’m building an Expense App with React Native and Redux and I have this two actions:

```
export const getExpenses = () => async (dispatch) => {
  await db.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    const data = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { description, name, value, date, type } = doc.data();
      data.push({
        key: doc.id,
        doc, // DocumentSnapshot
        description,
        date,
        name,
        value,
        type,
      });
    });
    dispatch({
      type: TYPES.GET_EXPENSES,
      payload: data,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: TYPES.SET_LOADING_EXPENSES,
      payload: false,
    });
    console.log('getExpenses', data);
  });
};
export const filterMonthInfo = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const info = getState().monthExpenses.data; // data returned by getExpenses()
  const currentMonth = getState().dateReducer.currentDate;
  const filteredInfo = info
    .filter(
      (data) => moment(moment(data.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')).format('MMMM YYYY') === currentMonth,
    )
    .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date));
  dispatch({
    type: TYPES.GET_FILTERED_EXPENSES,
    payload: filteredInfo,
  });
  console.log('filtermonth', filteredInfo);
};
```

In the Screen where I want to use the data returned by filterMonthInfo i have the following useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getExpenses();
    filterMonthInfo();
    getCurrentDate();
  }, []);
```

But since getExpenses is an async function, filterMonthInfo will  run first and is going to return undefined  because this last function is filtered based on data returned by getExpenses.
What is the best approach so I can make getExpenses run first and then filterMonthInfo?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a code after an async call is finished, you have to wait for it using Promise. write the code as

```
useEffect(() => {
    getExpenses()
  .then(()=>{
    filterMonthInfo();
    getCurrentDate();
     }
    );
  }, []);
```

or use async await as it makes syntax more clear